# Android- ActionBar hidden in emulator but showing in XML layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I used getSupportActionBar().hide(); The result is as expected, action bar hidden during app testing but in XML design view its still visible and thats a problem because i need to visualise how the app looks. Any way i can make it disappear in the XML design view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you are programmatically disabling actionbar, and your IDE doesn't know if it happens or not.

Add this to `res/values/style.xml` (create one if you don't have one)

```
<style name="AppThemeNoTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and put this under `application` tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoTitleBar"
```

so from the scratch (assuming you don't have anything, it should look like this.

res/values/style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemeNoTitleBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp" >

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ok thats clears it up a bit. though im a little confused as to what is ActionBar and what is Title? what does this do- "this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279222/android-whats-the-difference-between-a-title-bar-and-an-aciton-bar

Comment: also if i do as said above i dont need to do it programmarically too right? ie i dont need to edit .java file? and will it happen to all my activities? is yes then how can i chose which activity whould have or not have action bar?

Comment: These days ActionBar is mostly used instead of titlebar

Comment: This XML property is globally applied because the theme is applied to the application scope. So you don't need to do that in Activity classes (.java files)

Comment: What is your activity's name? put it there

Comment: sorry about that. error removed. i had copy pasted entire manifest file you gave but i just need to edit android:theme. But can you tell me how to apply different theme to different activities?

Comment: instead of putting the theme property in the application scope, you can put that in activity scope and apply to different activities. Take a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125163/apply-a-theme-to-an-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think you have theme for your activity in your manifest. if you remove your theme that contains the actionbar, problem is solved.